# Is there anything similar built-in with Android ListViews that is like an iOS Grouped UITableView?

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse, android-listview

Android developer newbie here....

In iOS, you can choose from two main styles (before customization) of a UITableView... normal and grouped. I really like the grouped look on some of my views for my apps in iOS.

Is there any similar built-in view styles for Android ListViews? Obviously I don't want it to look like iOS on Android, but if Android has their own "grouped" style I'd love to take a look.

Is there anything like that? Or do I just have to customize the basic ListView how it is?

BTW, I'm using a Base SDK of API 14 (ICS 4.0) so I *can* use the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researched I've learned that the answer to this is no.